# Is the converse to this theorem true?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, bilinear-form

In the book that I'm reading there is this one theorem which states.

Let V be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field F not of characteristic two. Then every symmetric bilinear form on V is diagonalizable.

I was wondering whether the converse is also true.

Meaning does a bilinear form being diagonalizable imply that the bilinear form was symmetric.

If it doesn't do you mind giving an explicit bilinear form where it doesn't hold true.

Comment: Yes, in matrices, if $D$ is diagonal, then $C^T D C$ is symmetric. Without matrices, a "diagonal" bilinear form is symmetric, a change of bases doesn't change it.

Comment: Diagonal matrices are symmetric, so yes.